# Can I do everything on Linux without keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Suppose that I have a desktop computer such that everything works except keyboard
. Is it possible to install and run Linux to this computer? I guess the answer is no as super user password requires keyboard but I'm not completely sure about this fact.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  "Linux" is generally installed using a specific *distribution*, of which there are many.  There may be one which is better suited to whatever you are trying to do, but if you don't explain what that is, we can't help you.

Comment: Linux is a kernel. There are hundreds of operating systems, with Linux as their kernel. Many of them run on hardware that have neither keyboard nor mouse (think for instance your TV, printer or broadband router). You need to be more specific here.

Comment: In fact, Android uses a linux kernel - and you don't need a keyboard, mouse, or even a super user password..

Comment: If "everything works except keyboard", then presumably you have working USB ports.  Use a USB keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can, as long as the proper tools are installed.

A few years ago, I ended up playing quite a bit with a Compaq TC1000 tablet.  It had a detachable keyboard and a stylus.

Typing without the keyboard was a bit of a challenge, but I had installed an on-screen keyboard that activated during the display manager login and once my graphical session was established and ready.  This setup used standard Debian packages during the Gnome 2.0 heyday.

I typically used it in its undocked mode to either browse the web or to take notes with Xournal.  Xournal's ability to either annotate PDF's or appear just like a legal pad made it very easy to take handwritten notes for later transcription.

If standard text was desired, the on-screen keyboard I was using could be trained to recognize your block handwriting, in some ways acting like the Palm Pilot-style Graffiti handwriting recognition, except that you could use your natural handwriting, rather than use a dedicated alphabet.

It was functional for a couple of years until the hardware on that tablet became incredibly slow (as software bloated) and then finally died altogether.  I see no reason that a modern touchscreen device couldn't do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can summon the virtual keyboard ([`onboard`](https://launchpad.net/onboard/)) to do any typing you may need. It's an extra package that you typically have to install:

```
# Ubuntu/Debian
$ sudo apt-get install onboard

# Fedora/CentOS/RHEL
$ sudo yum install onboard
```

*screenshot*

[image: ss of onboard]

It can be enabled to run at startup under the Assistive Technologies. See this blog post for more info, titled: [How to enable On-Screen Keyboard in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)](http://cmwelsh.com/enable-on-screen-keyboard-ubuntu-lucid-lynx).